# Spring Controller not returing to View

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I was integrating my application with instamojo for payment gateway integration.
and written given controller for WebHook URL

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/instamojo/Webhook", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView payment(HttpServletRequest request) throws JSONException{
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("bookingdetail");
        String payment_id = request.getParameter("payment_id");
        String status = request.getParameter("status");
        String email=request.getParameter("buyer");
        String name=request.getParameter("buyer_name");
        String phone=request.getParameter("buyer_phone");
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("custom_fields"));
        return view;
    }
```

I am able to get  payment_id, status, email, name but its not redirecting to defined ModelAndView part ("bookingdetail").Please suggest me some soultion.

Comment: That method makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If `bookingdetail`  is a url and not an actual view name you need to add `redirect:` to the view string:

```
  ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("redirect:bookingdetail");
```

Comment: I implement same but  nothing change.This is log I am getting on console 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:19:39:34 +0000] "POST /instamojo/Webhook HTTP/1.0" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:19:39:34 +0000] "GET /instamojo/bookingdetail HTTP/1.0" 200 11273                                                                           added one more controller @RequestMapping(value="/instamojo/bookingdetail", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView paymentR(HttpServletRequest request) throws JSONException{
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("bookingdetail");
        return view;
    }

Comment: look at log its status code is 302  so  its cross domain request. is it causing issue ? can you tell me some solution